# PHP Echo - echo result in popout div is Only echoing first result in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I have a search engine which displays results from a database and have used a reveal modal which opens a pop up box when a user clicks "Click Me For More Contact Info", however currently no matter which link is being clicked on any result, the same contact information is being echo'ed, this is the information from the first result.

could some one point me in the right direction showing me how to make it so that when a user clicks "Click Me For More Contact Info" the right contact information appears in the popup box for that result?

Thank you for any help, much appreciated!!

```
echo "<div id='myModal' class='reveal-modal'>";
echo "<h1>Modal Title</h1>";
echo "<p>Contact:" . $row['contact'] . "</p>";
echo "<a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<a href='#' data-reveal-id='myModal'>Click Me For More Contact Info</a>";
```

edit: the search results display fine, its just when the results are echo'ed into the pop up  div, this is the rest of my code:

```
include('config.inc');



    // Check and set username
$username = (isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 'guest');

// Check and set category
$category = (!empty($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : null);

// Check and set search
if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
$search = $_GET['search'];
}else{
$search = null;
}

// Check that $_GET['price'] is ASC if not set to DESC
// as static values its ok to directly put in the query 
if(isset($_GET['price']) && $_GET['price'] == 'ASC'){
$price = 'ASC';
}else{
$price = 'DESC';
}

if ($search !== null){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

$q   = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
// Bind the params to the placeholders
$q->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
}

if ($search !== null && $category !== null){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND category = :category";

$q   = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
// Bind the params to the placeholders
$q->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
}

if ($category !== null && $search !== null && isset($price)){

$sql = "SELECT   *
        FROM     people
        WHERE    MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        AND      category = :category
        ORDER BY price ".$price;

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
// Bind the params to the placeholders
$q->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
}

if ($category == null && $search !== null && isset($price)){

$sql = "SELECT   *
        FROM     people
        WHERE    MATCH (lname,fname) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)

        ORDER BY price ".$price;

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
// Bind the params to the placeholders
$q->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
}

if ($q){

//declaring counter
    $count=0;
    while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $row = $r;

    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $surname = $row['surname'];

//counter equals
$count++;

//insert an image every 5 rows
    if($count==5){
    $count=0;
   echo "<table width='50%' style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<div id='page-wrap'>";
echo "<div class='discounted-item freeshipping'>";

echo "<a href='images/box1.png' rel='lightbox'><img src='images/box1.png' width='20%' height='98%' /></a>";


echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title' style='width: 70%;'>AN AD CAN GO HERE</div><div class='reason' style='width: 29%;'><b>Ad Company</b></div></div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title1' style='width: 70%;'>Description about the advert from a company</div><div class='reason1' style='width: 29%;'>Category: Advert</div></div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title2' style='width: 70%;'>HELLO, User</div><div class='reason2' style='width: 29%;'></div></div>";


echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}




echo "<table width='50%' style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<div id='page-wrap'>";
echo "<div class='discounted-item freeshipping'>";

echo "<a href='./img/users/" . $row['category'] . "/" . $row['username'] . "/" . $row['filename'] . "' rel='lightbox'><img src=\"./img/users/" . $row['category'] . "/" . $row['username'] . "/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" width='15%' height='80%' /></a>";


echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title' style='width: 70%;'>" .$row['fname'] . "</div><div class='reason' style='width: 29%;'><b>". $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['surname'] ."</b></div></div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title1' style='width: 70%;'>" .   $row['lname'] . "</div><div class='reason1' style='width: 29%;'>Category:<br /> ".   $row['category'] . "</div></div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title2' style='width: 70%;'>Contact:" . $row['contact'] . "</div><div class='reason2' style='width: 29%;'>Price: &pound;".    $row['price'] . "</div></div>";



echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

echo "<div id='myModal' class='reveal-modal'>";
echo "<h1>Modal Title</h1>";
echo "<p>Contact:" . $row['contact'] . "</p>";
echo "<a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<a href='#' data-reveal-id='myModal'>Click Me For A Modal</a>";


}


}

else
echo "No results found for \"<b>$search</b>\"";
```

Comment: Post your database queries please.

Comment: How do you populate the other results?

Comment: From your code it looks like you are creating multiple pop up boxes in your while loop, how are you calling them when a link is clicked on. Do you have a way to identify the separate pop up boxes? Are you sure you are not just always opening the first pop up box rather the one that corresponds to the link.

Comment: @mrmryb yes currently it is just opening the first pop up box rather than the corresponding one, this is where i am stuck, any ideas of how i can link it to the corresponding link

Comment: Are you using standard javascript or a javascript library of any sort? You could post the code for the pop up function.

Comment: im using the script for the reveal div supplied by http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you gave:

`Just give your modal div the class "reveal-modal"and a unique ID (we'll use the ID to launch this modal)` and `By putting the "data-reveal-id" attribute on the anchor, when clicked the plugin matches the value of the "data-reveal-id" attribute (in this case "myModal") with an HTML element with that ID`.

At the moment you seem to be giving each modal the same id so all modal links will target the first one.

```
echo "<div id='myModal".$count."' class='reveal-modal'>";
echo "<h1>Modal Title</h1>";
echo "<p>Contact:" . $row['contact'] . "</p>";
echo "<a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<a href='#' data-reveal-id='myModal".$count."'>Click Me For A Modal</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, glad I could help. Good luck with the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve your data from your database, make sure you use `while($row=$req->fetch())` to retrieve ALL data. Then you have to select the correct row corresponding to your need.

Be careful, `$row` is an array containing all rows. Hence: `$row[0]['contact']` will contain the contact from the first row, `$row[1]['contact']` from the second, etc...

Comment: Bit confused, you wouldn't need to do a while loop if you are using fetchAll() which is what you seem to be implying with `$row[0]['contact']`?